# Is the time complexity of this function below is O(n) or O(1) constant?

Tags: python, algorithm, function

What is the Time complexity of the function below? Is it O(n) or O(1)?

```py
def find_words(grid, words):
    return [find_word(grid, word) for word in words]
```

Comment: @python_user there is an extra `s` in the function name and the call inside is without. OP has to show the implementation of `find_word`.

Comment: Thank you for editing the code, yes that's seem the right way. Yes I only put some parts of the code, but I would just like to know that Is the time complexity of this function is O(n) or O(1).

Comment: Without the implementation of `find_word` and the type of `grid` and `words` it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure how multiple complexities are calculated in stations like these but I think this is `O(n)*O(find_word)`, so if find_word is O(n) then the worst case scenario is `O(n*n)`? What I calculated might be hella wrong though since the n outside and the n inside are different, so something like `O(n)*O(m)` where m is the input size of the find_word.